# Error using OLS in statsmodel

Tags: python, linear-regression

I'm getting the error,

```
IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 1; 
dimension is 52 but corresponding boolean dimension is 184
```

from running the following code:

```
y = dat2['WaterWithdMunicipal']
X = dat2['WaterWithdIndustrial']
model = sm.OLS(y,X, data=dat2, missing='drop')
p = model.fit()
print(p.summary())
```

I know that the 2 arrays are different sizes (they contain different numbers of NaNs) but shouldn't the `missing = 'drop'` take care of that?

Answer (score 0):

`missing = 'drop'` will drop rows with missing values, which is why your X and y are different lengths.

There are different ways to fill it in, but I like `pandas.DataFrame.fillna`.

Answer (score 0):

This will erase rows as you expected, which contains at-least one missing value and will give you the required result.

```
dat2 = dat2.replace('', np.NaN)
dat2 = dat2.dropna()
y = dat2['WaterWithdMunicipal']
X = dat2['WaterWithdIndustrial']
model = sm.OLS(y,X, data=dat2)
p = model.fit()
print(p.summary())
```